# Changing the Background- Color of the X++ Editor of MSDAX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, morph-x

is there a Chance to Change the Background Color of the X++ Editor in the MorphX-Devlopment Environment in MSDAX 2012 ?

With Kind regards

Khashayar

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to extend the editor either using [Editor Scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa642309.aspx) or [using Visual Studio Managed Extensibility Framework](https://ax2012editorext.codeplex.com/). Changing the background color is not part of it, it seems.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we/I can't Change the Colors in the Script, or basically in the MorphX Development Environment. 

But I know that I can in Visual Studios. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with http://www.axassist.com/. This is an third party solution for Dynamics AX. I love it!